# How to set ng-show based on a variable from a service

Tags: angularjs

I am not sure what I should put on the title, so sorry in advance if the title is confusing. Also I am not very good with AngularJS either.

Let's say I have a factory "User" that contains a boolean value "activated". I have a "message" controller that injects "User".

```
angular.module('message', [])
    .controller('message', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, User){

        //some functions
        ...
        $scope.message = 'Helloworld';
        console.log('In Message Controller');
        console.log('debug message, User activated: ' + User.activated);    
    })
```

and I want to use ng-show in message.html, for example

```
<div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="User.activated">
    <p>Debugging: This only shows up if activated is true</p>
</div>
```

But the debugging message doesn't show up.

Is there anyway i can achieve this? Or if I am not supposed to do something like this, can someone suggest me another way to get the variable from "User" factory
and use it with ng-show? I want to prevent using $scope, for example

```
$scope.activated= function(){
    return User.activated;
}
```

on the controller because this way if I need to create several more controllers in the future I will have to set a $scope.activated in the controller.

Comment: Both answers are good, but I decided to use $rootScope for what I am trying to do first. Thank you Louie and Stepan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the is activated in the $rootScope, that way it is accessible to every controller and view like this:

In your controller:

```
angular.module('message', [])
.controller('message', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, User){

    //some functions
    ...
    $rootScope.user = User;
    $scope.message = 'Helloworld';
    console.log('In Message Controller');
    console.log('debug message, User activated: ' + User.activated);    
})
```

in your html

```
<div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="$root.user.activated">
    <p>Debugging: This only shows up if activated is true</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I also tried to set the activated value to $rootScope but was missing the "$root." part on the ng-show. Now that I put the exact same ng-show to my other html with another controller that injects the same User factory, and angularjs is throwing error with something like "TypeError: v2.activated is not a function" :( I will try to figure out the error myself first.

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with Eclipse which it doesn't update the html file somehow. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user3186311 so does this solved the problem? :) please don't forget to accept it as the answer if it was, so we can also help others find the  answer to their problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you need to use the service.

If you `User.activated` field should be carried out equally in all controllers, you must use a singleton.

If you `User.activated` method depends on the value in the controller, you must use the service instance.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/nb4m3zga/).

```
    angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleOneController', function($scope, ReuseService) {
    //We need do copy, because ReuseService is singleton 
    $scope.reusable = angular.copy(ReuseService);
    $scope.singleton = ReuseService;
  })
  .controller('ExampleTwoController', function($scope, ReuseService) {
    //We need do copy, because ReuseService is singleton 
    $scope.reusable = angular.copy(ReuseService);
    $scope.singleton = ReuseService;
  })
  .service('ReuseService', function() {
    return {
      varReuse: 'im not using yet',
      imReuseFunction: function(val) {
        this.varReuse = val;
      }
    }
  });
```

And HTML

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h3>
      ExampleOneController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm">
      Reusable variable: {{reusable.varReuse}}
      <br>Reusable variable singleton: {{singleton.varReuse}}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="reusable.imReuseFunction('one')">
        Reuse me
      </button>
      <button ng-click="singleton.imReuseFunction('one')">
        Reuse me singleton
      </button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h3>
      ExampleTwoController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm">
      Reusable variable: {{reusable.varReuse}}
      <br>Reusable variable singleton: {{singleton.varReuse}}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="reusable.imReuseFunction('two')">
        Reuse me
      </button>
      <button ng-click="singleton.imReuseFunction('two')">
        Reuse me singleton
      </button>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup I think I should use singleton because I want all my other controllers to have the same User.activated value and not just within that particular controller. Also in my use case the User.activated doesn't need to depends on any value in the controller. Is there other way to just inject the ReuseService singleton without calling $scope.singleton = ReuseService; ?

Comment: If you do not need to use the data from the service in the view, then you can not assign a service to `$scope` (`$scope.singleton = ReuseService`).

Comment: Otherwise, you need to carry out the assignment to have access to the service properties in the view